# Declare gameObject to animate

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I have a tutorial scene where you go through the level and reach a certain door, when you collide with that, it disables a canvas at the top, and animates the door. I've searched everywhere in the Scripting Docs, but can't find the solution. What type of variable do you declare the object to animate?

I tried declaring `public GameObject`/`Transform UIQuest` and `UIQuest.Animation.Play("DoorOpen")`, but it comes up with the error of not having the `Animation` in the API for that. Am I just doing this completely wrong or is there something simple I'm missing?

Complete script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DoorOpen : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject door;

    public Canvas UIQuest;

    void Start () {

    }

    void Update () {

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision doorCollision)
    {
        if (doorCollision.gameObject.name == "Door")
        {
            door.Animation.Play("DoorOpen");
            UIQuest.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what type of object is the door? Is it simply a plane you are rotating or an actual model? If so does the door have any animations defined for it as well as an Animation Controller attached to the object?

Comment: @Matthew Pigram It is a simple cube that I have rescaled to fit the size

Comment: You do not need anything special, you simply need to perform a rotation of the door over time, set the pivot of the door to the corner and rotate the door along the y-axis when conditions are met (i.e. when a collision is detected). Something like `gameobject.transform.Rotate(0, rotationAmount * Time.DeltaTime, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

As the gameobject is only performing a simple animation you do not need anything special (such as an AnimationController), you simply need to perform a rotation of the door over time, set the pivot of the door to the edge and rotate the door along the y-axis when conditions are met (i.e. when a collision is detected).

Something like :

```
gameobject.transform.Rotate(0, rotationAmount * Time.DeltaTime, 0);
```

You will also need logic to decide when to stop the rotation (i.e. when the door is fully open) unless you want a revolving doorway. Also if the door is just a sliding door this is even easier as you perform a translate instead of a rotate.

Comment: Just one simple question, how would I set the pivot point to the edge? I have tried using an empty GameObject and setting the door as a child, but it still rotates in the center

Comment: You are on the right track! Instead of rotating the door in this instance, you will instead rotate the empty gameobject. Make sure you place the gameobject on the edge of the door before rotating it. The way I would do this is in the door script create a public variable called PivotPoint of type Gameobject, then in the editor drag the empty gameobject that will be the pivot into the variable in the inspector, then in the script rotate the PivotPoint via its transform :D

Comment: The pivot seems to work, but Unity says it has no definition for DeltaTime. Is it deltaTime, or do I have to reference something else?

Comment: sorry yes, I think it is deltaTime, should be something like `Time.deltaTime`

Comment: Ok, really just one more question, what would some logic be to stop the rotation? Something I came up with that seems like it should work (but doesn't) is this: `if (pivot.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y == 83) { pivot.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true; }` but it still seems to rotate forever

Comment: You mostly have the right idea, except instead of freezing the component, simply stop running the rotate method. So you can kind of reverse your logic `if (pivot.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y < 83) { pivot.Rotate(0, 0, .1f); }`. There are better ways to do this though, if I have the time I will implement my own solution for this tonight and put it here.